# How do you specify the layout manager to use in a ContentPresenter in a custom control in Silverlight 3/4?

Tags: silverlight

I have a custom control I created that has ContentPresenter defined in generic.xaml.  I can successfully embed other controls into the custom control, but it appears to inherit the layout manager of the custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="custom:Widget">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="custom:Widget">
                <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">

                <!-- Custom Line, Ellipse code using Canvas from above... -->

                    <Grid>
                    <!-- This more local layout manager is overridden...why ? -->

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding 
                                              ContentTemplate}"/>
                    </Grid>
etc.....
```

In this case, I use a **Canvas** for the custom control, whereas I would like to specify something like **Grid** as the layout manager for the controls added to Content.  How do I do this ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "appears to inherit the layout manager of the custom control"? Also if you could post some xaml it would be helpful.

Comment: There's no reason your LayoutRoot couldn't be a Grid, unless there's something in that custom Xaml that requires it.  And even then you could have a Canvas within that Grid.  Maybe some more information about what you're trying to do would help?

Comment: So far this question isn't making any sense, how may child controls can a ContentPresenter have?  Ans: 1.  That child control may be a Grid, Canvas or anything else so there may other controls inside that but its the "top-level" child control which dictates layout to the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott,

Just make sure that your custom control (custom:Widget) derives from ContentControl and not Control.  Only ContentControl pay attention to ContentPresenters in the visual tree.

Jim McCurdy
[YinYangMoney](http://YinYangMoney.com"YinYangMoney")

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I am deriving from ContentControl, so that's not the problem.